# Verifone VX 675 GUI development

Tags: verifone

I have a Verifone VX 675 device. I am supposed to develop a GUI on it.

Do I need to have a Verifone ADK ?

Or can I use this folder given to me: `Mx800-vfi-toolchain-011a.tgz`? (The Mx800 is another device from Verifone).

Can some one please clear my doubt?

Comment: I am a newbie to Verifone POS development. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Will readers know what _Mx800-vfi-toolchain-011a.tgz_ is in order to advise you?

Comment: Mx800 is another device from Verifone. That is the folder I have been given.

Comment: No suggestions from anyone ? :|

Comment: It's a fairly niche topic, Hitesh, and the question is rather brief. What other research could _you_ do on the topic? Once you have posted your question, I advise you to keep researching on it. One of the key traits of a software engineer is persistence!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty hard to say from your description what kind of GUI are you building. Vx675 may come with eVo or V/OS operating systems. You may or not have ADK used there as both options are available. You should probably address those questions with the estate owner and the device vendor.